# How to say that something is very immature relative to something

Tags: comparisons

I'm looking for an expression to describe a situation when something (e.g. technology, software, science) is much less developed than some other representative of this category. Thus, much more error prone or just not so pleasant to use than its better competitor.

I was thinking about something like:

> This technology A is light years behind this other technology B.

or

> This technology A is far away from this other technology B.

Where:

- A - worse, immature, problematic
- B - better, mature, fully-developed

Are these sentences correct? The second one seems wrong to me, but the first seems fine because in Polish we have *coś jest lata świetlne za czymś*<sup>[1](http://sport.tvp.pl/mundial2018/37744610/mundial-2018-maradona-jest-lata-swietlne-za-messim)</sup>. What else could I use in this context?

Comment: A is ***primitive*** compared to B.

Comment: In the second sentence, "far away from" is ambiguous; it could be "far ahead of" or "far behind".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The A technology is lagged developed in comparison with B technology

Comment: The grammar is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A is very **[nascent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nascent)** compared to B.

> coming into existence; emerging

Answer (score 1):

"In its infancy," "the new kid on the block", underdeveloped.  Different words are appropriate depending on whether this is a new technology or program or one that has not kept pace with developments, and thus would be out of date, no longer maintained, and the like.

Answer (score -1):

A is inferior to B,
A is archaic compared to B, 
B is more advanced than A
A is the regressed version of B